Strange measurement of gravitational force using a spring dynamometer. Where did I go wrong?
As is known, value of gravitational force is equal to $mg$.
I decided to consider process of measurement of gravitational force using a spring dynamometer in more detail.
I obtained that value of gravitational force from point A to point B is variable: value of at point A is $0$ and value at point B is $mg$ (see picture below).
And value of gravitational force at some point between A and B is less than $mg$.

It seems strange.
How is it possible? Where did I go wrong?

Could you explain in more detail what you saw when doing the experiment and what you expected?

@David_h I saw that measurement of force was variable and I thought it was strange but it turned out that it should be.

You are not wrong. Your physical reasoning is correct. I think you are confusing the gravitational force with the gravitational acceleration. The acceleration is constant; the force is proportional to mass.
Restated: If the marker displacement $\Delta x$ changes, it means that $mg$ has indeed changed because you must have changed the mass. Gravitational force does change: It's proportional to mass! What's constant is the gravitational acceleration $g$ (which is not the same as the force).
